# smarty->assign() doesn't evaluate the code?

Tags: php, html, smarty, template-engine, assign

I am writing a PHP-Script which assigns some html-code to my templates.

**PHP-File:**

```
$smarty->assign("PLACEHOLDER", getCode());
$smarty->display('index.html');

function getCode(){ 
     return "{literal}some code which I want to get evaluated ...{/literal}"; 
}
```

**HTML-File:**

```
{$PLACEHOLDER}
```

I know i could use `{eval var=$PLACEHOLDER}` instead of `{$PLACEHOLDER}` which would work perfectly, the only thing is that I have about 500 templates and I won't change the html-code of all of them. Is there a way I can evaluate the code directly when I assign it to the template?

Comment: No, why should it? It is not part of the template, it is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [{eval}](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.eval.tpl)

> {eval} is used to evaluate a variable as a template. This can be used for things like embedding template tags/variables into variables or tags/variables into config file variables.
>
> If you supply the assign attribute, the output of the {eval} function will be assigned to this template variable instead of being output to the template.

So in your HTML-File use the following:

```
{eval var=$PLACEHOLDER}
```

Comment: I only just saw that this is an ancient question XD Was pushed to the front page by your edit probaly